# Why does tensorflow show inaccurate loss?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm using Tensorflow to train a network to predict the third item in a list of numbers.

When I train, the network appears to train quite well and do well on both the training and test set. However, when I evaluate its performance myself, it seems to be doing quite poorly.

For example, at the end of training, Tensorflow says that the validation loss is `2.1 x 10^(-5)`. However, when I compute it myself, I get `0.17 x 10^0`. **What am I doing wrong?**

Here's code that can be run on Google Colab:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
def create_dataset(k=5, n=2, example_amount=200):
    '''Create a dataset of numbers where the goal is to always output the nth number'''
    # UPGRADE: this could be done better with numpy to just generate all the examples at once

    example_amount = 1000
    x = []
    y = []
    ans = [x, y]
    for i in range(example_amount):
        example_x = np.random.rand(k)
        example_y = example_x[n]
        x.append(example_x)
        y.append(example_y)
    return ans


def tensorize(tensor_like) -> tf.Tensor:
    '''Turn stuff into tensors'''
    return tf.convert_to_tensor(tensor_like, dtype=tf.float32)

def split_dataset(dataset, train_split=0.8, random_state=42):
    '''
    Takes in a list (or tuple) where index 0 contains the inputs and index 1 contains the outputs
    outputs x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test, train_indexes, test_indexes all as tf.Tensor
    '''
    indices = np.arange(len(dataset[0]))
    return tuple([tensorize(data) for data in train_test_split(dataset[0], dataset[1], indices, train_size=train_split, random_state=random_state)])


# how many numbers in each example
K = 5
# the index of the solution
N = 2
# how many examples
EXAMPLE_AMOUNT = 20000
# what percentage of the examples are in the training set
TRAIN_SPLIT = 0.5
# how long to train for
epochs = 50

dataset = create_dataset(K, N, EXAMPLE_AMOUNT)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test, train_indexes, test_indexes = split_dataset(dataset, train_split=TRAIN_SPLIT)

model_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(K,), name="input")
model_dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, name="dense1")(model_input)
model_dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, name="dense2")(model_dense1)
model_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, name="output")(model_dense2)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=model_input, outputs=model_output)
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss="mse")
history = model.fit(x=x_train, y=y_train, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), epochs=epochs)
# the validation loss as Tensorflow computes it
print(history.history["val_loss"][-1]) # 2.1036579710198566e-05

# the validation loss as I compute it
val_loss = tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.keras.losses.MSE(y_test, model.predict(x_test))).numpy()
print(val_loss) # 0.1655631
```

Comment: You need to check `val_acc` as the validation accuracy for the obtained result by `print(history.history["val_loss"][-1])`.

Comment: @Pro Q is my answer helpful or not? If not, please leave a feedback therefore I can edit it.

Comment: Thank you for the bump! It did indeed help! It took a bit for me to verify and for me to understand the difference between (x, 1) and (x) shapes and how broadcasting might mess up the  loss, but once I figured that out I forgot to come back here and accept. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you miss is that the shape of `y_test`.

```
y_test.numpy().shape
(500,) <-- causing the behaviour
```

Simply reshape it like:

```
val_loss = tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.keras.losses.MSE(y_test.numpy().reshape(-1,1), model.predict(x_test))).numpy()
print(val_loss) # 1.1548506e-05
```

Also:

```
history.history["val_loss"][-1] # 1.1548506336112041e-05
```

Or you can `flatten()` both of the data while calculating it:

```
val_loss = tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.keras.losses.MSE(y_test.numpy().flatten(), model.predict(x_test).flatten())).numpy()
print(val_loss) # 1.1548506e-05
```